# I need help getting the information for each point in my Mapbox map to display data when clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to get information to show when a user clicks on a point on the map. I am including the code below. I need to know what I can do to make this code perform. Currently it just displays the map but when I click on a point on the map no information is displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Points on a map</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.31.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.31.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmdsYWZsZXVyIiwiYSI6ImNqMmFoNWJsMTAwODQycW83ZTVtZHN6ODgifQ.DQFq_99bvRdBhkOs_vnZAQ'; // replace this with your access token
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/rglafleur/cj7j1tz2z62a92rmruh4x7qgl' // replace this with your style URL
    });

    map.on('click', function(e) {
  var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
    layers: ['lpin1_database'] // replace this with the name of the layer
  });

  if (!features.length) {
    return;
   }

  var feature = features[0];

  var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: [0, -15] })
    .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
    .setHTML('<h3>' + feature.properties.Nme_of_Chld + '</h3><p>' + feature.properties.No_Episodes + '</p>')
    .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
    .addTo(map);
 });
    </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I am thinking the problem is that I dont have the correct name of the layer in the code where it asks me: "replace this with the name of the layer".

Comment: Does anyone know if its possible to have password enabled users to sign into a mapbox map and update data. Not actually sign into the account of the map but make the map interactive so that a user can update the data.